# Where are is the TARGETDIR variable defined?

Tags: visual-studio, wix

From what I understand, by looking at stackoverflow posts, is that TARGETDIR means `root directory of the partition with the most free space` But where is this defined? Are there more variables like it?

I would like to know where I can find documentation on TARGETDIR, and variables like it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the documentation on MSDN:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372064(v=vs.85).aspx